# How to save a user’s image and display it

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views, django-templates

I have a user profile model.

```
class Profile(models.Model):

    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    image = models.ImageField(User,default='default.jpg', upload_to='profile_pics',) #default avatar user /download avatar user 
    avatar = models.CharField(max_length=300, null=True, blank=True) #field for storing url from a social network

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(Profile, self).save(*args, **kwargs)

        img = Image.open(self.image.path)

        if img.height > 300 or img.width > 300:
            output_size = (300, 300)
            img.thumbnail(output_size)
            img.save(self.image.path)
```

It has two fields for the image.

1- regular default avatar (input **image**) it can be set by the user and after downloading it will be saved in the media / profile_pics folder.

2 field (input **avatar**) - to store the avatar url from outside (social network). I also have two authorizations, regular and social ([python-social-auth](https://python-social-auth.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html)). When authorizing a call through social networks, I use the function to get the url of the user address:

```
def get_avatar(backend, response, user=None, *args, **kwargs):

    if backend.name == 'vk-oauth2': 
        url = response.get('photo', )   
    if url:
        user.profile.avatar = url
        user.profile.save()
```

I get a link of this kind (**url** variable):

`https://sun9-12.userapi.com/c852132/v852132234/118b6c/aB0GoDEWzaw.jpg`

and save this url **user.profile.avatar**.

In the template, I output:

```
<img  src="{{user.profile.image.url }}"> - #default avatar user/download avatar user
<img  src="{{user.profile.avatar}}"> - #social avatar (url) user
```

How do I make sure that when authorizing through social authorization, the image from the url is downloaded and saved in a folder as for imagefield (**profile.image**)? That is, during the atvorization through social networks, the picture was downloaded by url, and it was saved as if this field were image and I was able to access it through user. **profile.image.url**, not a separate **user.profile.avatar** field?

I would be grateful for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could download the image via `urllib.request`:

```
import urllib.request
import mimetypes

    def save_image(user):
        url = user.profile.avatar
        filename = user.id + mimettypes.guess_extension(urllib.request.urlopen(url).headers['content-type'])
        path = os.path.join(settings.MEDIA_ROOT, filename)

        urllib.request.urlretrieve(url, path)

        user.image = path
        user.save()
```

depending on your storage location, you might change the path, but this should be a sketch of a possible solution.

EDIT: As you are using an ImageField, this should also work:

```
import urllib.request

    def save_image(user):
        url = user.profile.avatar
        file = urllib.request.urlopen(url).read()

        user.image = file
        user.save()
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the answer, as soon as I test, I will unsubscribe here

Comment: how can I then display this in the template?

Comment: and how can I get the path where the picture is saved?